# Facebook popup box for html bootstrap website

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap

I have an price tracker website. This is built on bootstrap.

I have tried to add the facebook like popup box from various pages and it is not seem to be working.

Is there a easy way to add the facebook like popup box for bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Sure think what your looking for is not a pop up .. but its called a modal. Below I will give a quick out lay of what you need to do:

**HTML:**

```
<button style="margin:20px;" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal in old way</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      This is a Message
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<button id="newbtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Launch modal in new way</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn:focus,.btn:active:focus,.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,.btn:active.focus,.btn.active.focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#newbtn").click(function() {
   BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Say-hello dialog',
    message: 'Hello, World!'
    });
  });
```

Just make sure you add the CDN for bootstrap and you should be all set to go! Take out the button functionality and replace it with a `href` tag on what ever you want to click on and it should work.